# Is there a way to remove a "wrong" duplicate flag from a question?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicates

Recently I have found a question which **I believe** is wrongly marked as a duplicate of another one.

The other question looks very similar and partially addresses the issues raised by the current question. So at first glance the current question may pass as a duplicate. But I still believe it is not to be judged as a duplicate after a thorough inspection.

Is there a way to remove this duplicate flag? What are possible options I, a user with pretty low reputation, can try to revert the question's status?

#### What I have already tried

I raised an "**in need of moderator intervention**" flag and tried to explain the situation thoroughly along with two screenshots within the 500 character limit. The flag was reviewed and its status changed to "*helpful*". But the question *in question* is still marked as a duplicate of the other.

---

#### Current issue

By default <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> in GNOME cycles through

- open applications (instead of individual windows)
- from all the workspaces (instead of only the current one)

One needs to press <kbd>↓</kbd> key to show individual windows of the same application, see this screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJTE6.png]

In [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/957045/how-do-i-make-alt-tab-cycle-through-individual-windows-only-in-current-workspa) *in question* OP asks for a way to change both the behaviours, i.e. they want to make <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> cycle through **individual windows** instead of applications only in **current workspace**. [The other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464946/ubuntu-gnome-force-alt-tab-to-only-switch-on-current-workspace) only deals with the "*only in current workspace*" part and doesn't touch upon "*individual windows instead of applications*" part at all. If the fixes from the other question are applied, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> will still cycle through open applications (instead of individual windows) but now only in the current workspace.

Screenshot of my "**in need of moderator intervention**" flag:
[image]

Comment: @pomsky probably a temporary issue with imgur...

Comment: @pomsky Thanks. Btw, as one of the close voters there, I will say that not only does linking the question *not* offend me, but the exact opposite: If a closure is correct, you give people an opportunity to defend it. If a closure is wrong (as this one *looks* to be--I'll likely vote to reopen soon), you protect us from causing further harm and also give us the opportunity to cast reopen votes. Of course, it is also possible for someone to wrongly change their mind about a good close vote or defend a bad one, but the point remains that you are only giving us opportunities, not taking them away.

Comment: No need to keep updating your question to explain yourself, we understand and this is exactly what Meta is for, disscusion of the main site. Your disclaimer and update are not needed.

Comment: @MarkKirby Thanks! I've removed them.